# Argument type mismatch Exception while opening a new stage

Tags: java, exception, javafx, scene, stage

In my java app, I just want to open a new fxml window upon login success.
When login successfully done the new window successfully open up.
But even though everything's working fine I am getting an error with the line :

```
root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/frmMain_ui.fxml"));
```

I am confused is it the problem of defining the location or not..
My project outline :

folder:src > folder:ui > .fxml files

folder:src > folder:base > .java Controllers files

folder:src > folder:MainView > Main.java, ShowForm.java

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.Tab$1.invalidated(Tab.java:209)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.scene.control.Tab.setSelected(Tab.java:185)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:722)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:735)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.findNearestAvailableTab(TabPane.java:794)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.lambda$new$17(TabPane.java:691)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.add(FXMLLoader.java:168)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$PropertyElement.add(FXMLLoader.java:1403)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:788)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at MainView.ShowForm.showFrmMain**(ShowForm.java:20)**
    at base.frmLogin_base.openFrom_Main**(frmLogin_base.java:56)**
    at base.frmLogin_base.ActionLogin**(frmLogin_base.java:69)**
    at base.frmLogin_base.do_btnLogin**(frmLogin_base.java:43)**
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

this is my ShowForm.java :

```
public class ShowForm {
    public void showFrmMain(Stage mainStage){
        Parent root = null;
        mainStage = new Stage();
        mainStage.setTitle("Welcome to Dashboard");
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../ui/frmMain_ui.fxml"));
            mainStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            mainStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my login action method :

```
private void ActionLogin(){
        try {
            if(this.LoginProcess(frmLogin_tbxUsername.getText().toString(), frmLogin_tbxPassword.getText().toString())){
                UpdateStatus();
                alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Information");
                alert.setHeaderText("Success !");
                alert.setContentText("Successfully Logged In !");

                alert.showAndWait();

                openFrom_Main();  // open form method
                frmLogin_btnLogin.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            }else{
                alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Information");
                alert.setHeaderText("Failed !");
                alert.setContentText("Incorrect Credentials, Please try again !");

                alert.showAndWait();

                frmLogin_tbxUsername.clear();
                frmLogin_tbxPassword.clear();
            }
        }catch (Exception ERROR){
            ERROR.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My openForm_Main() Method :

```
private void openFrom_Main(){
        new MainView.ShowForm().showFrmMain(new Stage());
    }
```

there is nothing in frmMain actually.
Here is my frmMain_base.java (Controller) :

```
package base;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class frmMain_base {

    @FXML
    private Menu frmMain_TitleBar;

    @FXML
    private Label frmMain_txtDateTime;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> frmMain_tableCol_From;

    @FXML
    private TabPane frmMain_tabMsgPane;

    @FXML
    private Tab frmMain_tabContacts;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem frmMain_MenuItemAbout;

    @FXML
    private TableView<?> frmMain_tableView_Message;

    @FXML
    private Label frmMain_txtFullName;

    @FXML
    private ListView<?> frmMain_ListView_Contacts;

    @FXML
    private Label frmMain_txtStatus;

    @FXML
    private Button frmMain_msg_btnSend;

    @FXML
    private Tab frmMain_tabInbox;

    @FXML
    private Tab frmMain_Tab_Milestones;

    @FXML
    private TextField frmMain_msg_tbxMessage;

    @FXML
    private Tab frmMain_Tab_Issues;

    @FXML
    private SplitPane frmMain_SplitPane;

    @FXML
    private TextArea frmMain_msg_tbxMsgBox;

    @FXML
    private Tab frmMain_Tab_Resolved;

    @FXML
    private Button frmMain_btnLogout;

    @FXML
    private Tab frmMain_Tab_Features;

    @FXML
    private Font x1;

    @FXML
    private Color x2;

    @FXML
    private TabPane frmMain_TabPane;

    @FXML
    private Font x3;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> frmMain_tabCol_Message;

    @FXML
    private Color x4;

    @FXML
    private Label frmMain_txtRank;

    @FXML
    void do_ClickTitleBar(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void do_MenuItemAbout(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void do_tabContacts_changing(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void do_OnMouseClick_ListView_Contacts(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void do_tabInbox_changing(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void do_msg_btnSend(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void do_btnLogout(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

And here is my frmMain_ui.fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1100.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="base.frmMain_base">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu fx:id="frmMain_TitleBar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#do_ClickTitleBar" text="FiKHSONS INTERNATIONAL Software Dashboard" />
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem fx:id="frmMain_MenuItemAbout" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#do_MenuItemAbout" text="About" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <SplitPane fx:id="frmMain_SplitPane" dividerPositions="0.23385300668151449, 0.8708240534521158" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <items>
        <AnchorPane>
          <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" minWidth="60.0" prefWidth="-1.0" style="&#10;" text="Messages" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="false">
              <font>
                <Font size="18.0" fx:id="x1" />
              </font>
              <textFill>
                <Color blue="0.624" green="0.624" red="0.624" fx:id="x2" />
              </textFill>
            </Label>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" layoutX="4.0" layoutY="43.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="499.0" prefWidth="246.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="45.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <TabPane fx:id="frmMain_tabMsgPane" layoutX="51.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="245.0" prefWidth="243.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                <tabs>
                                  <Tab fx:id="frmMain_tabContacts" onSelectionChanged="#do_tabContacts_changing" text="Contacts">
                                    <content>
                                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                             <children>
                                                <ListView fx:id="frmMain_ListView_Contacts" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="14.0" onMouseClicked="#do_OnMouseClick_ListView_Contacts" prefHeight="212.0" prefWidth="243.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                    </content>
                                  </Tab>
                                  <Tab fx:id="frmMain_tabInbox" onSelectionChanged="#do_tabInbox_changing" text="Inbox">
                                    <content>
                                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                             <children>
                                                <TableView fx:id="frmMain_tableView_Message" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="212.0" prefWidth="243.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                                  <columns>
                                                    <TableColumn fx:id="frmMain_tabCol_Message" editable="false" prefWidth="140.0" resizable="false" text="Message" />
                                                    <TableColumn fx:id="frmMain_tableCol_From" editable="false" minWidth="4.0" prefWidth="84.0" resizable="false" text="From" />
                                                  </columns>
                                                </TableView>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                    </content>
                                  </Tab>
                                </tabs>
                              </TabPane>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <GridPane layoutX="5.0" layoutY="162.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="217.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="176.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="157.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="135.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="43.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="frmMain_msg_btnSend" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#do_msg_btnSend" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="54.0" text="Send" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <TextField fx:id="frmMain_msg_tbxMessage" promptText="Enter your message here !" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                 </children>
                              </GridPane>
                              <AnchorPane layoutX="22.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <TextArea fx:id="frmMain_msg_tbxMsgBox" editable="false" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="233.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="545.0" prefWidth="430.0">
        <children>
          <Label alignment="CENTER" font="$x1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" style="&#10;" text="Tasks &amp; Scheduling" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="$x2" wrapText="false" />
                  <AnchorPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="57.0" prefHeight="478.0" prefWidth="537.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="57.0">
                     <children>
                        <TabPane fx:id="frmMain_TabPane" layoutX="143.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="478.0" prefWidth="663.0" style="-fx-border-width: 3.5; -fx-border-color: gray;" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" tabMinWidth="80.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <tabs>
                            <Tab fx:id="frmMain_Tab_Issues" text="Issues">
                              <content>
                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                              </content>
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab fx:id="frmMain_Tab_Milestones" text="Milestones">
                              <content>
                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                              </content>
                            </Tab>
                              <Tab fx:id="frmMain_Tab_Features" text="Features">
                                <content>
                                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                </content>
                              </Tab>
                              <Tab fx:id="frmMain_Tab_Resolved" text="Resolved">
                                <content>
                                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                </content>
                              </Tab>
                          </tabs>
                        </TabPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                  <Button fx:id="frmMain_btnLogout" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="619.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#do_btnLogout" text="Logout" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="13.0" />
        </children>
      </AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane prefWidth="100.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
          <children>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.1882998171846435" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="549.0" prefWidth="160.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <GridPane layoutX="-51.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="99.0" prefWidth="137.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="frmMain_txtFullName" alignment="CENTER" cache="true" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="txtFullName" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="10.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label fx:id="frmMain_txtRank" alignment="CENTER" cache="true" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="txtRank" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="10.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label alignment="CENTER" cache="true" text="Mood Coming Soon" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="10.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                 </children>
                              </GridPane>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="100.0" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
                           <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" font="$x1" style="&#10;" text="News" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="$x2" wrapText="false" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
    <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <children>
        <Label fx:id="frmMain_txtStatus" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="-1.0" text="Status" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
          <font>
            <Font size="11.0" fx:id="x3" />
          </font>
          <textFill>
            <Color blue="0.625" green="0.625" red="0.625" fx:id="x4" />
          </textFill>
        </Label>
        <Pane prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <Label fx:id="frmMain_txtDateTime" font="$x3" maxWidth="-1.0" text="Date &amp; Time" textFill="$x4" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
      </children>
      <padding>
        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
      </padding>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

I am actually not sure why this exception is occurring even though everything's working fine.
It will so helpful if anyone can point it out and give me a clear explanation what I am doing wrong or what I should do in right ways.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: The problem comes from your `frmMain_ui.fxml` file and its controller class. Please [edit] your question to include those.

Comment: Done editing...check please

Comment: @James_D Thanks bro

Comment: Yup, you got it. Was just about to post an answer... Note the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#onSelectionChangedProperty) tells you the correct type of event for these handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have solved it finally.

The problem was with the EventHandler in my frmMain_ui.fxml Controller Class (frmMain_base.java) ..

It was :

```
@FXML
void do_tabContacts_changing(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void do_tabInbox_changing(ActionEvent event) {

}
```

The Solution is it should be "Event" instead of "ActionEvent", because these are the Events for invoking the changing state of a component :

```
@FXML
void do_tabContacts_changing(Event event) {

}

@FXML
void do_tabInbox_changing(Event event) {

}
```

Thanks @James_D bro for getting me in the direction.

Comment: Also note that if you don't need the event parameter (and in most cases you don't), you can just define the method with no parameters and the `FXMLLoader` will figure it out. That saves looking up the parameter type for each handler.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks again for the helpful tip